# Can we say that MSE of MLE is always at most equal to that of UMVUE?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, mse, umvue

The question is in the title. I was wondering if that is the case, because we are considering a more general class, rather than focusing on the class of unbiased estimators, as we do in case of UMVUE. Please tell me the proof if this is true, otherwise please give me counter examples of MSE of UMVUE less than and greater than MLE. I couldn't prove this.